# How to manually Simulate Physics properly on Unity?

Tags: unity, physics, networking

I'm trying to simulate physics manualy in a Unity 3D game. I've turned off Physics "Auto Simulation" in Project Settings and wrote this piece of code (it is more or less the [unity doc sample](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Simulate.html))

```
private void Update()
{
    this.timer += Time.deltaTime;
    while (this.timer >= Time.fixedDeltaTime)
    {
        this.timer -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;

        controller.ApplyForces(controls);
        Physics.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

But when I play the game, movements are lagging a lot.
In fact, I can explain it: my game runs at 120 fps. The `Time.fixedDeltaTime` is set to 0.01667 (60fps). So 1 out of 2 frames are not simulating physics! In other words, half of my Update calls don't enter the `while` loop, which produce the jump effect.

I'm sure i'm missing something... what is the recommended way to do this? Should I call `Physics.Simulate` in `FixedUpdate`?

EDIT:

As someone asked me in the comments (then deleted the comment), I'm simulating Physics manually for networking reason. With manual physics, I can do predictions and corrections. [Here's a link that describes the problem](https://codersblock.org/blog/client-side-prediction-in-unity-2018)

EDIT2:

Thanks to @DMGregory and [his excellent answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/105113/139279), I figured out that the problem comes from the lack of interpolation of my player rigidbody:
[InterpolationMode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-interpolation.html) seems to be handled by Unity when autosimulation is set to ON, which is not my case.

So now I'm looking how to handle this myself.

Comment: [Normally mismatches between the physics tick rate and display framerate are solved with interpolation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/132835/39518).

Comment: Arg, I was afraid of this answer. Thanks for the link, I will check it out!

Comment: Oh! @DMGregory I just read your other post (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/105113/139279) and just understood one thing : Unity, with autosimulation ON, magically interpolates rigidbodies with "interpolate" mode, **but does NOT with autosimulation OFF!**. I have the exact same problem by turning my RBs to "no interpolation" mode even with auto-simulating physics!

Comment: Fortunately, you can roll your own interpolation. Have two copies of each GameObject: one that's invisible and used for simulation, and one that's visible, with a script that interpolates its parameters according to updates from its simulated copy.

Comment: Can we reasonably affirm that Unity does this with autosimulation and interpolated rigidbodies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of research, I have a better understanding of this.

1. the problem I describe is a very common problem due to unsync between frame rendering timestep and physics fixed timestep. [Unity solves this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-interpolation.html) automatically with the `interpolationMode = interpolate` of rigidbodies.
2. when simulating physics manually, Unity do not interpolate thoses rigidbodies for us anymore. We have to do it manually, [as @DMGregory suggests](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/105048/smooth-camera-follow/105113#105113)
3. another option is lower fixedDeltaTime a lot to minimize desyncs, as @shingo suggests. But rendering timestep is not constant! And if the game runs at 120fps, the fixedTimestep whould be very small and CPU instensive.
4. I highly recommand to read [this article](https://johnaustin.io/articles/2019/fix-your-unity-timestep), which suggests to use `Application.targetFrameRate` and `fixedDeltaTime` to synchronise those timesteps to the same framerate.

Finally, I set the framerate to 60Hz whith those two properties: this is ok for rendering and not too intensive for CPU physics. And the game seems fluid again.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you need a small `fixedDeltaTime` value (eg. 0.01).

You can simulate physics in Update, but you'd better drag this script to the front row in Script Execution Order settings.

Comment: But if I want my game to run 120fps, I need 0.008s. of fixed delta time, which is very, very low. I don't want physics to run that frequently, I'm sure there are some better solutions

Comment: Could you tell me why do you believe there is a better solution? You have to call `Physics.Simulate` to move objects, otherwise do it manually.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I have the feeling that lowering the fixed delta time will be more CPU intensive, specially with simulation correction due to networking problems (however, I'm also considering this option)

Comment: Yes, high fps is more CPU intensive. For an online game maybe you just want to synchronize the states in a low frequency.